# recyclerview.setLayoutManager()

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

What is the use of  recyclerview.setLayoutManager() in this code?
Please elaborate it in detail.I know about recyclerview but i am confused on what is the use of setLayoutManager() here?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int NEW_WORD_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

private WordViewModel mWordViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    final WordListAdapter adapter = new WordListAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

Comment: Do you know what is a `RecylclerView` ? Seems you are asking us to do your analyze...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

More than a year late but the idea behind the `setLayoutManager` is to set the layout of the contents, i.e. list of repeating views in the recycler view. If you scroll down to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager)) here, it will tell you that there are several strategies for lists and grids so that should give you a clue. Furthermore, it tells you that without it, `RecyclerView` will not function i.e. there is no out of the box default.

So if you want e.g. to set the `LinearLayout`to be horizontal (by default it is vertical) then you have to specify that.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
    = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myItems = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myItems.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```